AADSTS500011 Error when trying to access role assignments in Azure Government Tenant
I am receiving the following error when trying to access role assignments in our Azure government tenant:
The portal is having issues getting an authentication token. The experience rendered may be degraded.
Additional information from the call to get a token:
Extension: Microsoft_Azure_AD
Resource: graph
Details: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx was not found in the tenant named xxxxxxxxgov.onmicrosoft.com. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Trace ID: 4ee33a05-daf2-447f-b132-27dcbe7c1d00 Correlation ID: a0c63a12-500f-45d8-a3ae-e3a6e08c484e Timestamp: 2024-10-18 13:16:26Z
The principal name comes back as an Azure Active directory enterprise application.
We use our Azure commercial login to access our government tenant.  At login, we sign into the organization.  I was able to PIM elevate to owner with no issue, and only get this error when trying to look up role assignments or add role assignments.
Tried logging out and logging back in, checked access, and everything seems normal.  Not sure where to start on this one though unfortunately.
